# Unordered list from specific table column

Tags: php, html, mysql

If I have a table called "photographs" with columns: "id, gallery_name, filename, type, size, caption", how can I create an unordered list with only the unique values from the gallery_name column listed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly (i.e. I'm not missing some complex aspect of what you're trying to do), the following MySQL command should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `gallery_name` FROM `photographs`
```